# Writing the proper init function in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios4

Here is my init function for a View Controller:

```
- (id) initWithStartup: (NSDictionary *) _startup investor: (NSDictionary *) _investor chat_id: (NSString *) _chat_id chat_name: (NSString *) _name
{
    self = [self initWithNibName: @"PLNewChatViewController" bundle: nil];

    if(self)
    {
    }

    return self;
 }
```

Is it normal/necessary to have the following:

```
    self = [self initWithNibName: @"PLNewChatViewController" bundle: nil];
```

Should the xib file be loaded automatically?

Comment: First off, it should be self = [super .....];  And the answer is, it depends.  This is one correct way to do it.

Comment: If you just call `[super init]` it should pick up the xib with the appropriate name from the main bundle, assuming the XIB has the same name as the class.

Answer (score 1):

So, question name: Writing the proper init function in IOS

Rules for coding initializers in subclasses:

1. You should call supers designated initializer in your designated initializer
2. You should call your designated initializer from other initializers
3. Why do you use "_" characters in method name, and in parameters names, in Objective-C use camel case
4. You should override supers designated initializer, it should call your designated initializer (because client can see the initializers of super)
5. If you subclassing UIView, designated initializer is not called when your view objects are subsequently loaded from the nib file. So you should override both methods initWithCoder: and - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect
6. When you calling some methods of your class in initializer methods, it can be unsafe. because those methods can be overridden in subclass of your class. (you can not mark your method as final, like in Java) So be careful

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MultipleInitializers.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html